# Flask-SocketIO making sure socket disconnects from client correctly

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I added the Flask-SocketIO library to my Flask application to handle live connections and testing it with cookies being sent to the backend after the user completes a specific action. This is in case the user closes their browser or the webpage before issuing another HTTP request to the URL. I found that the browser won't save the cookie being set with `document.cookie` in javascript until it receives the cookie back from the server in response. Since adding the WebSocket and testing it in the development environment, the socket does emit the cookie correctly. However when I attempt to use `ctrl-C` in the terminal, it won't fire the signal, and even after I close the terminal and the browser/webpage, `localhost` is still listening on the port. I know how to manually kill the process with `taskkill` but my concern is that the socket connection with the client is left open after they had already closed the webpage/browser. I'm assuming this can be bad for performance on the backend and possibly cause some security risks, though I'm not sure. This might be because I'm not handling the socket connection and emitted message on the backend correctly but that's because the example code in the documentation was difficult to follow. Here is the documentation: https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

Can someone please answer this question?

__init__.py:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, current_app
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

csp = {
    "default-src": [
        "'self'",
        'https://www.youtube.com'
    ],
    'script-src': [ "'self'",
                    'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js',
                    'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js',
                    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js'],
    'style-src': ["'self'",
                  'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'],
    'img-src': ["'self'",
                'data:',
                'https://i.ytimg.com' ],
    'font-src': ['data:']
}

config = {
    "CACHE_TYPE": "simple",
    "DEBUG": True,
    "SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI": "sqlite:///site.db",
    "SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS": False,
    "SQLALCHEMY_ECHO": False
}
socketio = SocketIO()
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_mapping(config)
    socketio.init_app(app)

    from flask_app.main.routes import main
    app.register_blueprint(main)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        socketio.run(current_app)

    return app
```

main/routes.py:

```
from flask import render_template, session, request, current_app, Blueprint, redirect, url_for, json, make_response
from flask_app import cache
import os

main = Blueprint("main", __name__)

@main.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", title="Home")

@main.context_processor
def inject_template_scope():
    injections = dict()

    # Use this method to check if the client has consented to the use of cookies.
    def cookies_check():
        value = request.cookies.get('consent')
        return value != None
    injections.update(cookies_check=cookies_check)
    return injections
```

run.py:

```
from flask_app import create_app
```

base.html:

```
<html>
 <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"
    integrity="sha256-yr4fRk/GU1ehYJPAs8P4JlTgu0Hdsp4ZKrx8bDEDC3I="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

base.js:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
 function cookieConsent() {
   var socket = io();
   const now = new Date();
   document.cookie = "consent=consented:true,dateTime:" + now + ",lang:" + navigator.language;
   socket.on('connect', function() {
       socket.emit('consent cookie', {consent_cookie: document.cookie});
   });
 }
}
```

Project Hierarchy:

```
project/
|_ flask_app/
   |_ main/
      |_ routes.py
   |_ templates/
      |_ base.html
   |_ static/
      |_ js/
         |_ base.js
   |_ __init__.py
|_ run.py
```

Environment Variables:

```
FLASK_APP : run.py
FLASK_ENV : development
```

Comment: Can you share how you run your application?

Comment: I just updated my post with my project hierarchy and environment variables, in my terminal at the project/ directory path I run the command flask run.

Answer (score 0):

`socketio.run(app)` start a development server at the port 5000.

So when you execute `flask run` flask calls function `create_app()` and expects an app. Your function however doesn't actually return app because `socketio.run(app)` is blocking. When you press CTRL+C it stops this line.

Comment: I just updated my post with my project hierarchy and environment variables, in my terminal at the project/ directory path I run the command `flask run`. Flask works by looking for the start file (this being `run.py`) that is set by the `FLASK_APP` environment variable and look for it inside the flask_app directory and then executes the file. The \__init__.py file is executed and since `run.py` imports the `create_app()` function, it gets called.  I'm not very well versed in all things python but this seems to work so I guess you don't need to make a direct method call.

Comment: `flask run` makes a function call but your function doesn't return app. Instead, it starts a development server.

Comment: okay, so I should make a direct call to the `create_app()` function and get the app returned and then send it to socketio.run()? I updated my run.py code, is that the correct way of starting the socket so that it can be terminated when I send SIGTERM to terminal?

Comment: I would do it that way. Flask uses werkzeug as a development server by default(when you run `flask run`). Looks like they had to create their embedded server instead(I don't know maybe werkzeug doesn't support WebSockets). They briefly mention the embedded server in the deployment section of their docs.

Comment: I found out that the issue was the python package, eventlet. The Flak_SocketIO documentation states to have either eventlet or event installed to use socketio for production purposes. I use both gunicorn and Nginx to serve my application on Heroku so it makes sense to use gunicorn and add the necessary information to the Nginx config file. But with eventlet installed on my environment, it was not allowing for CTRL + C to be used. After uninstalling eventlet everything seemed to work fine in development